# Store multiple values from sql select in bash

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash

I am trying to store each value from the following sql select statement and store them in separate variables using bash.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 mysqlhost="thehost"
 mysqldb="thedb"
 mysqlun="theusername"
 mysqlpw="thepassword"
 mysqlconnection="--disable-column-names --host=$mysqlhost --user $mysqlun --password=$mysqlpw --database=$mysqldb"

declare -a pinIDs=$(mysql $mysqlconnection -e "SELECT pinID FROM somewhere WHERE something = something";)
```

I get the following result when I use code

```
echo $pinIDs
```

8 11 23 26

I need to store each of those values into their own variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets to put output in array `pinIDs`. Replace

```
declare -a pinIDs=$(mysql $mysqlconnection -e "SELECT pinID FROM somewhere WHERE something = something";)
```

by

```
declare -a pinIDs=( $(mysql $mysqlconnection -e "SELECT pinID FROM somewhere WHERE something = something";) )
```

Then see output of: `declare -p pinIDs`

Answer (score 0):

For others that are using this to learn. What I did after fixing the brackets in order to put the result into an array such as (8 11 23 26) instead of 8 11 23 26, was this:

```
cnt=${#pinIDs[@]}
for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++ ))
do
echo "pinId: ""${pinIDs[$i]}"
done
```